# How to join several unrelated tables

Tags: sql, function, postgresql-9.3

I have five queries and each of them will return me single column multiple row output. I want to to write a function which will contain all of these queries.
Can anyone help?

**query 1:**

```
Select Col1 as X from Table1;
```

**query 2:**

```
Select Col3 as Y from Table2;
```

From a function I want to get a table which will have columns
`X, Y`

How to club these queries under single function?

Comment: you should also provide what you've tried so far. Is there any relation between Table1 and Table2?

Comment: I edited the title of the question to reflect the main point of the question, as I understood it. If I misunderstood the question, please edit it further.

Comment: What does it mean "a function which will contain all of these queries"? You want to put the results of these queries into one long list of results? Or you want to put one field of each table into a column or ... ?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger, If I understood the question correctly, OP said that he wants to get one table with two columns `X, Y` as a result.

Comment: So the Xs and Ys need to be related somehow ... or are thy just randomly assigned?

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger  I want each query output(single col multiple row) populate each column in the table returned by function. As five queries are there the returned table should have five coulmns. Is it possible?

Comment: And which values of the fife queries should be returned in the same row? By rownumber? Then you should go with Vladimir Baranov's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the UNION operator:

```
SELECT
    column_1
FROM
    tbl_name_1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    column_1
FROM
    tbl_name_2;
```

Comment: Probably `UNION ALL` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `ROW_NUMBER()` to each of the queries and join them by the row number.
Depending on number of rows returned by each of the query you'd join then by `inner`, `left` or `full` join.

Example below assumes that two queries return the same number of rows.

```
WITH
CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT Col1 as X, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1) AS rn
    FROM Table1
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT Col3 as Y, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col3) AS rn 
    FROM Table2
)
SELECT
    CTE1.X, CTE2.Y
FROM
    CTE1
    INNER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.rn = CTE2.rn
```

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ytd(MMYY character varying, MMYY1 character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(name character varying, ratio bigint, ratio1 bigint) AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
RETURN query
SELECT col1 as name from t1, 
Select col2 as ratio from t2,
Select col3 as ratio1 from t3


END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION ydt2(MMYY character varying, MMYY1 character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
Same parameter will be passed in each sql

Answer (score 0):

If there is a relation between the two tables, try using a [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).
Maybe a simple `inner join` would be possible here?

```
select Col1 as X from Table1
join 
on Table1.Col1_name = Table2.col3_name
```