# How to Select two tables and Concatenate them

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `Staffs` and `Customers` I want to select the records of each independent of each other but in one query in a such a way that neither of them affects each others' records. for example 
[Selecting the customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw8og.png),
[Selecting staffs records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb9fO.png)
,
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7oxW.png) 
As long JOINING and UNION is not for this purpose

Comment: may be a cross join ?

Comment: you have some relations between  matt and johnny ??? otherwise why not simmons ??

Comment: @scaisEdge 
no relation just one two execute two queries in one which are independent of each other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join several unrelated tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452243/how-to-join-several-unrelated-tables)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Join

```
Select * from Staffs inner join Customers;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get them together into one dataset, you don't need a concatenation. You just need a UNION.

I don't know the exact name of your tables or which RDBMS you are using, but you might try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Staffs

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMERS;
```

If you have the same column names in each, you could do:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC AS "Staffs_ColumnC"
FROM Staffs

UNION ALL

SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB AS "Customers_ColumnB", ColumnC
FROM Customers;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to union them together:

```
select id, name, lastname, 'staff' as which
from staffs
union all
select id, name, lastname, 'customer'
from customers;
```